# Loop through an array, sort data, copy and save it to another file

Tags: excel, vba

I have the following script which works fine:

```
Sub cautare_copiere()

Dim datasheet As Worksheet 'de unde este informatia copiata
Dim raportsheet As Worksheet 'unde este copiata informatia
Dim salveaza As Worksheet 'unde se copiaza informatia pentru output
Dim asd As String
Dim ultimulrand As Integer
Dim i As Integer 'numaram randurile

'setez variable

Set datasheet = Sheet1
Set raportsheet = Sheet2
Set salveaza = Sheet4
asd = raportsheet.Range("B2").Value
valoare = raportsheet.Range("D2").Value
cantitate = raportsheet.Range("F2").Value

'sterge datele din tab-ul Raport
salveaza.Range("A5:L500").ClearContents 'ajustez range-ul de unde sterg datele - daca am informatie multa, il maresc
salveaza.Range("A5:L500").ClearFormats

'se duce in tab-ul Copy, cauta si copiaza
datasheet.Select
ultimulrand = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

'cauta printre randuri si selecteaza informatia pe care o cautam

With datasheet
    For i = 2 To .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
        If .Cells(i, 22) = asd Then
            'Copierea unui range este relativa la rand....
            .Rows(i).Range("A1:AA1").Copy _
                    salveaza.Range("A200").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)

        End If
    Next i
End With

'salveaza Output intr-un fisier nou cu numele din casuta B2 din Raport
With raportsheet

Dim xPath As String

xPath = Application.ActiveWorkbook.Path
    salveaza.Copy
    Application.ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=xPath & "\" & .Range("B2").Value, FileFormat:=51
    Application.ActiveWorkbook.Close False

End With

'selecteaza casuta B2 din Raport dupa ce a terminat de copiat informatia
With raportsheet

   .Select
    .Range("B2").Select

End With

End Sub
```

In Raport sheet, cell B2 I have a drop-down list and I have to select a name, then I run the script, search through my entire sheet (Copy sheet) and copy all rows with selected name to Output sheet then create a new file and save it as selected name. I have to do this for every single name, and I have around 100 names.

**My question is:** Is there any chance to modify this and instead selecting the name from the drop-down menu (cell B2 from Raport sheet) just press a button (Search) and loop through all the names, create and save files automatically?

I know how to handle arrays, but just the basics as I’m still new to VBA.

Also, if this could be improved to run faster as I search through over 50k rows.

Comment: I'd say, look into either AutoFilter or Advanced Filter for such task. Or create a dictionary with names and concatenated row numbers to be used later.

Comment: Thank you! I'll have a look into this.

Answer (score 0):

Try this concept below:

1. Read the data into an array. For 50K rows it should fit the memory
2. Make a unique list of keys
3. Process all keys in a loop
4. Copy matching records to another array
5. When finished, paste the entire array to an empty sheet and save it as a file

Notes:

1. this code below is just a demo and is not tested
2. it's a bit confusing clearing `salveaza` till column L while copying data till column AA so this example below will work on columns A to AA

So:

```
Dim aBuf(), aBufOut()
Dim asd As Variant         ' it must be a variant type
Dim i As Long, k As Long
Dim cc As New Collection
Dim bProc As Boolean
Dim lastrow as Long
Dim lastcol as long
Dim outrow as Long

lastcol = 27  ' 27=AA
lastrow = datasheet.cells(datasheet.Rows.Count, 22).End(xlUp).Row
aBuf = datasheet.Range(cells(1, 1), Cells(lastrow, lastcol))  
On Error Resume Next
For i = LBound(aBuf, 1) To UBound(aBuf, 1)
    cc.Add aBuf(i, 22), CStr(aBuf(i, 22))
Next
On Error GoTo 0

' here you have a collection of unique key values in collection cc

For Each asd In cc
   redim aBufOut(1 to 500, 1 to lastcol)
   outrow = lbound(aBufOut, 1)

   With datasheet
       For i = 2 To lastrow
           If aBuf(i, 22) = asd Then 'Copierea unui range este relativa la rand....
               For k = lbound(aBuf, 2) to ubound(aBuf, 2)
                   aBufOut(outrow, k) = aBuf(i, k)
               Next
               outrow = outrow + 1
           End If
       Next i
   End With
   salveaza.Range(Cells(5, 1), Cells(500, lastcol).ClearContents 'ajustez range-ul de unde sterg datele - daca am informatie multa, il maresc
   salveaza.Range(Cells(5, 1), Cells(500, lastcol).ClearFormats
   salveaza.Range(Cells(5, 1), Cells(outrow + 3, lastcol)) = aBufOut

   With raportsheet

       Dim xPath As String

       xPath = Application.ActiveWorkbook.Path
       Application.ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=xPath & "\" & asd, FileFormat:=51
       Application.ActiveWorkbook.Close False

  End With
Next
```

Comment: This is a hint to show you an alternative solution to answer your question and give you some ideas, not a complete and working app. Please complete it. `salveaza` may not have a value assigned.

Comment: Ok! I'll have a look on this. Thank you!